# My Proof for subset of a finite set is finite

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let X be a finite set and Y a subset of it.

If $X=\emptyset$ then Y is finite.

If $X \neq \emptyset$, then we have, by definition of a finite set, the following bijection:
$$
f:I_n\rightarrow X
$$
Where $I_n = \{1,...,n\}$.

Since $Y\subset X$, $f^{-1}(Y) \subset I_n$ and $f|_{f^{-1}(Y)}:f^{-1}(Y)\rightarrow Y$.

So If I'm able to show that $f^{-1}(Y)$ is finite, we'll have:
$$
g:I_k\rightarrow f^{-1}(Y)
$$
bijective, and I can compose functions to get:
$$
h:I_k\rightarrow Y
$$
concluding that Y is finite.

Let's suppose that $X = I_n$ and $Y\subset X$.

For $n = 1$ we have $I_n = \{1\}$, wich implies that $Y=\{1\}$ or $Y=\emptyset$, in both cases $Y$ is finite.

Now let's suppose the theorem is valid for an arbitrary n, and therefore, let's try to prove that it's valid for $n+1$.

Since we have $Y\subset I_{n+1}$, we can have $Y=I_{n+1} \rightarrow$ Y is finite, and $Y \neq I_{n+1} \rightarrow \exists a \in I_{n+1} - Y$.

Let's now define a bijection k:

$$
k:I_{n+1}\rightarrow I_{n+1}
$$

where $k(a) = n+1$.

Therefore:

$$
k|_Y:Y\rightarrow k(Y)\subset I_{n+1} - \{n+1\} = I_n
$$

And by our induction hypothesis, we can see that $k(Y)$ is finite.

If $k(y)$ is finite and $k|_y$ is a bijection, we can compose functions, as I said in the beginning, to see that Y is finite

---

My question is... I needed to suppose that $X=I_n$ to prove it. It's ok to suppose that? And if so, why?

Comment: If X is finite, you can pick a member and label it 1 and set it aside.  Pick another member and label it 2 and set it aside. etc.  Since X has a finite number of elements, you will eventually pick them all and label them (1,2,..,n).

Comment: But thats the intuition for a bijection between $I_n$ and $X$...

Comment: Here’s a hint for an alternative approach. Take your bijection for the original set. If your subset is nonempty, let $n_1$ be the smallest number in $I_n$ such that $f(n_1)\in Y$, let $n_2$ be the smallest number in $I_n\setminus\{n_1\}$ such that $f(n_2)\in Y$, etc...

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Thank you! But what do you think about my proof?

Comment: @BrunoReis the supposition that $X=I_n$ is a little odd because it isn’t true in general. Usually one writes $X=\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ by virtue of the bijection $i\mapsto x_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ since finite sets aren’t necessarily sets of natural numbers e.g. finite set of squares in the plane but instead are *enumerated* by the naturals (or a finite subset of them).

Comment: Another, possibly easier, way is to prove that the size of subset is always less or equal to the size of the original set.